# Apache POI PPT (Java) - Updating PPT Chart underlying values keeping formatting (position, dimension, colors)

Tags: java, charts, formatting, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am trying to produce several reports (i.e. N PPTX files) based on different inputs/for different users on the same PPTX template I created.

I have several preformatted XSLFChart on the PPTX template that contains a single dummy underlying values. Charts are already formatted (i.e. legend, color, position, ... both the shape and the related text).
Each chart contains an underlying datasheet as placeholder that I need to substitute with a dynimic values. I have this value in different data structure. I am successful in updating a PieChart (see below example) but I failed with barChart barStackedChart and others.

```
public static void updatePieChart(XSLFChart chart, Map<String, String> pieChartValues) {
    // Embedded Excel workbook that holds the chart data
    String pieChartTitle = "MyUpdatedPieChart";
    POIXMLDocumentPart xlsPart = chart.getRelations().get(0);
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

        CTChart ctChart = chart.getCTChart();
        CTPlotArea plotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();

        CTPieChart pieChart = plotArea.getPieChartArray(0);
        //Pie Chart Series
        CTPieSer ser = pieChart.getSerArray(0);

        // Series Text
        CTSerTx tx = ser.getTx();
        tx.getStrRef().getStrCache().getPtArray(0).setV(pieChartTitle);
        sheet.createRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue(pieChartTitle);
        String titleRef = new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 0, 1, true, true).formatAsString();
        tx.getStrRef().setF(titleRef);

        // Category Axis Data
        CTAxDataSource cat = ser.getCat();
        CTStrData strData = cat.getStrRef().getStrCache();

        // Values
        CTNumDataSource val = ser.getVal();
        CTNumData numData = val.getNumRef().getNumCache();

        strData.setPtArray(null);  // unset old axis text
        numData.setPtArray(null);  // unset old values

        // set model
        int idx = 0;
        int rownum = 1;
        for (Object key : pieChartValues.keySet()) {
            CTNumVal numVal = numData.addNewPt();
            numVal.setIdx(idx);
            numVal.setV(pieChartValues.get(key));

            CTStrVal sVal = strData.addNewPt();
            sVal.setIdx(idx);
            sVal.setV((String) key);

            idx++;
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue((String) key);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(Double.valueOf(pieChartValues.get(key)));

        }
        numData.getPtCount().setVal(idx);
        strData.getPtCount().setVal(idx);

        String numDataRange = new CellRangeAddress(1, rownum - 1, 1, 1).formatAsString(sheet.getSheetName(), true);
        val.getNumRef().setF(numDataRange);
        String axisDataRange = new CellRangeAddress(1, rownum - 1, 0, 0).formatAsString(sheet.getSheetName(), true);
        cat.getStrRef().setF(axisDataRange);

        // updated the embedded workbook with the data
        try (OutputStream xlsOut = xlsPart.getPackagePart().getOutputStream()) {
            wb.write(xlsOut);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Here the same code adapted for BarChart. It compiles fine, but when I try to open the PPT "PowerPoint found a problem with comment in FileName.pptx".

```
public static void updateBarChart(XSLFChart chart, Map<String, String> pieChartValues, String pieChartTitle) {
    // Embedded Excel workbook that holds the chart data
    POIXMLDocumentPart xlsPart = chart.getRelations().get(0);
    try (XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

        CTChart ctChart = chart.getCTChart();
        CTPlotArea plotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();

        CTBarChart barChart = plotArea.getBarChartArray(0);
        //Pie Chart Series
        CTBarSer ser = barChart.getSerArray(0);

        // Series Text
        CTSerTx tx = ser.getTx();
        tx.getStrRef().getStrCache().getPtArray(0).setV(pieChartTitle);
        sheet.createRow(0).createCell(1).setCellValue(pieChartTitle);
        String titleRef = new CellReference(sheet.getSheetName(), 0, 1, true, true).formatAsString();
        tx.getStrRef().setF(titleRef);

        // Category Axis Data
        CTAxDataSource cat = ser.getCat();
        CTStrData strData = cat.getStrRef().getStrCache();

        // Values
        CTNumDataSource val = ser.getVal();
        CTNumData numData = val.getNumRef().getNumCache();

        strData.setPtArray(null);  // unset old axis text
        numData.setPtArray(null);  // unset old values

        // set model
        int idx = 0;
        int rownum = 1;
        for (Object key : pieChartValues.keySet()) {
            CTNumVal numVal = numData.addNewPt();
            numVal.setIdx(idx);
            numVal.setV(pieChartValues.get(key));

            CTStrVal sVal = strData.addNewPt();
            sVal.setIdx(idx);
            sVal.setV((String) key);

            idx++;
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
            row.createCell(0).setCellValue((String) key);
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(Double.valueOf(pieChartValues.get(key)));

        }
        numData.getPtCount().setVal(idx);
        strData.getPtCount().setVal(idx);

        String numDataRange = new CellRangeAddress(1, rownum - 1, 1, 1).formatAsString(sheet.getSheetName(), true);
        val.getNumRef().setF(numDataRange);
        String axisDataRange = new CellRangeAddress(1, rownum - 1, 0, 0).formatAsString(sheet.getSheetName(), true);
        cat.getStrRef().setF(axisDataRange);

        // updated the embedded workbook with the data
        try (OutputStream xlsOut = xlsPart.getPackagePart().getOutputStream()) {
            wb.write(xlsOut);
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

I would like to create a single function that given the template chart (XSLFChart) and the data structure (may be also List - thus one String[] for each datasheet row) containing the new values updates the chart on the PPT file.

Any suggestion/solution? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What happens if you check what `xlsPart` really is after `POIXMLDocumentPart xlsPart = chart.getRelations().get(0);`? I bet is is not the `/ppt/embeddings/Microsoft_Excel_Worksheet.xlsx` but `/ppt/charts/style1.xml` or `/ppt/charts/colors1.xml`. If so you overwrites the `style1.xml` or `colors1.xml` with the `Excel` data. So no wonder that the `PowerPoint` file is corrupt then.

Comment: Nice guess! It actually contains "Name: `/ppt/charts/style1.xml` - Content Type: `application/vnd.ms-office.chartstyle+xml`
Tomorrow I will check it out better. I was already successful in displaying the chart correctly but if I tried to access the data from the produced PPT the chart disappeard with #REF written where the label where. I thought it was a convention that first element was the xslx datasheet...assumptions are always the problem.

Comment: @AxelRichter I am almost finalised the procedure, I will post the entire solution shortly. I am trying to find a method to understand the type of chart (e.g. PieChart, BarChart,...) I am editing. Looping on an already prepared slidedeck template and just updating charts underlying data would be cool to understand dynamically the type of chart instead of having this information from another file that describe the template. Any hint on this? Thx

Comment: The charts differ in the kind of arrays in [CTPlotArea](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTPlotArea.java). [CTPlotArea.sizeOfPieChartArray()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTPlotArea.java#CTPlotArea.sizeOfPieChartArray%28%29) > 0 -> pie chart ...